# What is happening when a script encounters an error in one of the commands?

Tags: shell-script, dash

I used alien to convert an RPM to a .deb. I did NOT use alien's script conversion; I'm converting by hand.  Indeed, the script did barf on some non-compatible syntax.  My question is NOT about how to fix this incompatibilty, but rather about how the script continues to execute successfully, despite encountering an error.

Here's the problematic section:

```
if [ "`/bin/echo '\c'`" == "" ]; then
   ECHO_ESC="/bin/echo"
else
   ECHO_ESC="/bin/echo -e"
fi
```

This causes the following "error":

```
./avsetup_mcc: 11: [: \c: unexpected operator
```

Despite this, the script continues to execute perfectly.  So, what's happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[` is not a "special builtin", and according to [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_08_01) a `Utility syntax error (option or operand error)` of a non-special builtin `Shall not exit` a non-interactive shell ("script").

So much as for why the shell does not exit. The script functions perfectly because `ECHO_ESC` is set to something sane no matter how the `if` branches.

Unlike the error message suggests, the error does not come from the `\c` but the `==` which is invalid to use with `[` (string equality is tested with a single `=`), but shells that support `[[` (which supports `==`) seem to allow `==` even for the single bracket notation (e.g. `bash`, `ksh`). Note that the above code does *not* error under bash, so you might want to consider retagging your question.

Comment: Ah.  Debian uses dash now. Thanks for the great answer.

Comment: So . . . are you saying that the else branch still successfully executes, thus setting the value of ECHO_ESC?

Comment: Exactly that :-)

Comment: I'm taking a wild guess regarding where your question is coming from: It is not the `if` statement itself which fails as `[` is not a part of `if` but a command/builtin on its own, thus the expression evaluates to false and the `if` executes the `else` branch "as expected".